# Reshaping wide to tall data over multiple variables

Tags: r, reshape

Currently my data looks like this:

```
wide.df <- read.table(header = T, sep = ",", text = "
ID, left.mid.brain, right.mid.brain, left.lat.brain, right.lat.brain, score, group
100, 18 , 4, 29, 30, 40, 0
101, 19,  7, 33, 40, 29, 0
103, 19, 19, 22, 30, 33, 0
200, 29, 30, 22, 33, 11, 1
233, 100, 33, 22, 44, 55, 1")
```

I need to convert my data into long format to look something like this:

```
ID  group  left.or.right  mid.or.lat    brain     score
100   0          0             0           29        40   # 0 = left, 0=lat 
100   0          1             0           30        40   # 1 = right, 0=lat
100   0          0             1           18        40   # 0 = left, 1 = mid
100   0          1             1            4        40   # 1 = right, 1 = mid
101   0          0             0           33        29   # 0 = left, 0 = lat
.
.
.
.
.
233   1           1            1            33        55   # 1= right, 1= mid
```

Where `left.mid.brain` , `right.mid.brain` , `left.lat.brain`, `right.lat.brain` are changed into factors but their values are still kept and the each participant has four lines each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **tidyverse** (specifically the **dplyr** and **tidyr** packages) are very good at operations like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

long.df <- wide.df %>% 
  gather(variable, brain, left.mid.brain, right.mid.brain, left.lat.brain, right.lat.brain) %>% 
  mutate(
    left.or.right = ifelse(grepl('left', variable), 0, 1),
    mid.or.lat = ifelse(grepl('lat', variable), 0, 1)
  ) %>% 
  select(ID, group, left.or.right, mid.or.lat, brain, score) %>% 
  arrange(ID)

    ID group left.or.right mid.or.lat brain score
1  100     0             0          1    18    40
2  100     0             1          1     4    40
3  100     0             0          0    29    40
4  100     0             1          0    30    40
5  101     0             0          1    19    29
6  101     0             1          1     7    29
7  101     0             0          0    33    29
8  101     0             1          0    40    29
9  103     0             0          1    19    33
10 103     0             1          1    19    33
```

Comment: Since `grepl` returns logical values, you can just convert those to numeric instead of assigning manually in `ifelse`: `left.or.right = as.numeric(grepl("left", variable))`

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr`/`tidyr`-based method that should scale fairly well. After you create long-shaped data, you'll have columns with values like `"right.mid.brain"` that you want to split into `"right"` and `"mid"`—`dplyr::separate` does this easily, splitting on `"\\."` and avoiding too much hardcoding. It sticks you with a dummy column, which I'll drop later.

At that point, you'll have this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# 0 = left, 0 = lat 
wide %>%
  gather(key, value = brain, -ID, -score, -group) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("left.or.right", "mid.or.lat", "dummy"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  head()
#>    ID score group left.or.right mid.or.lat dummy brain
#> 1 100    40     0          left        mid brain    18
#> 2 101    29     0          left        mid brain    19
#> 3 103    33     0          left        mid brain    19
#> 4 200    11     1          left        mid brain    29
#> 5 233    55     1          left        mid brain   100
#> 6 100    40     0         right        mid brain     4
```

If you had more complicated recoding you needed to do, you could use some `forcats` functions to recode factor levels. In this case, it's simple enough to just convert columns based on conditions like `left.or.right == "right"`, which if true becomes 1, and if false (i.e. if it's left), 0. Select the columns in the order you want.

```r
long <- wide %>%
  gather(key, value = brain, -ID, -score, -group) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("left.or.right", "mid.or.lat", "dummy"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  mutate(left.or.right = as.numeric(left.or.right == "right"),
         mid.or.lat = as.numeric(mid.or.lat == "mid")) %>%
  select(ID, group, left.or.right, mid.or.lat, brain, score) %>%
  arrange(ID)

head(long)
#>    ID group left.or.right mid.or.lat brain score
#> 1 100     0             0          1    18    40
#> 2 100     0             1          1     4    40
#> 3 100     0             0          0    29    40
#> 4 100     0             1          0    30    40
#> 5 101     0             0          1    19    29
#> 6 101     0             1          1     7    29
```